# Are characters used as index of an array implicitly converted to byte/int?

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

I examined the code below and it seems to me that `char` values, when inserted as an index of an array (in this example, an `int` array) is converted to ascii format.

E.g. `char` 'a' will become 97 (decimal format).

I was wondering: **is this an implicit conversion into the int/byte type?**

```
public int getNoOfUniqueCharacters(String str) {
        int[] charSet       = new int[128];
        char[] characters   = str.toCharArray();
        int numOfUniqueChars = 0;
        for (char curChar : characters) {
            if(charSet[curChar] == 0) {
                ++numOfUniqueChars;
            }
            ++charSet[curChar];     // Is char being implicitly converted to int/byte here?
        }
        return numOfUniqueChars;
    }
```

Thank you in advance for taking time to look at my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char` is an integral type. Each `char` has a numeric value between `0` and `2^16-1`.

Therefore, when you use a `char` as an index to an array, that numeric value is used, since arrays always have an `int` index.

The conversion that takes place is called [widening primitive converion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2).